# Extract <a> content in Python, Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I actually make a script, which check auction portal for new interested auctions for me. Now script choose the item name, category, add time and make a list of auctions. Here is start my problem. My code:

```
#List of auctions
time.sleep(2)
lists= driver.find_elements_by_class_name("vela__item__1FnoI")
print ("Found " + str(len(lists)) + " auctions")

for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="vela__item__1FnoI"]//a'):
    print (link.get_attribute('href') + "-" + link.text)
```

Now it's look horrible:

```html
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="dae57d0d-9570-4693-bb7f-8aa31ab24699", element="49e4afcd-f6c3-4b62-bba0-a3b21e08c78d")>
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="dae57d0d-9570-4693-bb7f-8aa31ab24699", element="3f2a9f43-26b8-40f6-a4b6-497d46e41598")> etc
```

Please help me to achive this result wiev:

http://allegro.pl/doris-wozek-dla-lalek-3f-nosidlo-torba-posciel-15k-i6735944795.html - DORIS WÓZEK DLA LALEK 3F NOSIDŁO TORBA POŚCIEL 15K

http://allegro.pl/sukienka-ubranko-dla-lalki-barbie-de-lux-i6739976160.html - Sukienka ubranko dla lalki Barbie! DE LUX!

HTML search result:

```html
<article class="item__item__2lO83 ">
                    <div class="vela__item__1FnoI">
                        <div class="vela__item__details__1di9R">
                            <div class="photo__thumbnail__1SaYl ">
                                <noscript>
                                    <i><img src="https://1.allegroimg.com/s128/0166b6/964534be46848305f499770a74f1" alt="DORIS WÓZEK DLA LALEK 3F NOSIDŁO TORBA POŚCIEL 15K" /></i>
                                </noscript>
                            </div>
                            <h2 class="header__title__2RWO4">
                                <a href="http://allegro.pl/doris-wozek-dla-lalek-3f-nosidlo-torba-posciel-15k-i6735944795.html">DORIS WÓZEK DLA LALEK 3F NOSIDŁO TORBA POŚCIEL 15K</a>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article><article class="item__item__2lO83 ">
                    <div class="vela__item__1FnoI">
                        <div class="vela__item__details__1di9R">
                            <div class="photo__thumbnail__1SaYl ">
                                <noscript>
                                    <i><img src="https://e.allegroimg.com/s128/0129ef/ec0ceef742ce9cdecbe3465a67fe" alt="Sukienka ubranko dla lalki Barbie! DE LUX!" /></i>
                                </noscript>
                            </div>
                            <h2 class="header__title__2RWO4">
                                <a href="http://allegro.pl/sukienka-ubranko-dla-lalki-barbie-de-lux-i6739976160.html">Sukienka ubranko dla lalki Barbie! DE LUX!</a>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `print (item)` you are printing the `WebElement` `to_string()` method. To print the text use

```
print (item.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use below code to exract links and link text:

```
for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="vela__item__1FnoI "]//a'):
    print(link.get_attribute('href') + "-" + link.text)
```

Comment: [print (link.get_attribute('href') + "-" + link.text)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

WTF?

Comment: `Python2.x` or `Python3.x`?

Comment: Python 2.x (lenght)

Comment: I delete "]" from first line, but not working again. No print results, no errors :/

Comment: And if simply `import time` and add `time.sleep(2)` just after `driver.get("URL")`? Same result?

Comment: I use time.sleep all time and page load it's not a problem. Python print me: Found 26 auctions, sa page is loaded.

Comment: Hmm... weird... I double-checked my code with provided `HTML` sample and get desired output.. Can you share page `URL`?

Comment: view-source:http://allegro.pl/dziecko?string=lalka&startingTime=1&bmatch=base-relevance-floki-5-nga-bab-1-2-0222

Comment: oh... yeap. Class name seem to be `"vela__item__1FnoI "`, but not `"vela__item__1FnoI"`- there is a space in the end... Answer updated. Please mark it as `Accepted` if it finally solved your issue. Thanks

Comment: Your answer is not updated, i correct xpath, but the same situation - not result....... :/ I'm tired this. Two hours and i cant write two code lines :D
I updated code in my post, it's the same like yours.

Comment: Ooook... Try this `'//div[normalize-space(@class)="vela__item__1FnoI"]//a'`. This should match both `"vela__item__1FnoI "` and `"vela__item__1FnoI"`

Comment: Working, but with doubled link:

http://allegro.pl/lalka-dzidzius-nteraktywny-bobas-mowi-zamyka-oczy-i6740518205.html-
http://allegro.pl/lalka-dzidzius-nteraktywny-bobas-mowi-zamyka-oczy-i6740518205.html-Lalka Dzidziuś NTERAKTYWNY BOBAS MóWi,zamyka oczy
http://allegro.pl/ubranka-dla-lalki-barbie-cyrkonia-plaszcz-z-trenem-i6740511479.html-
http://allegro.pl/ubranka-dla-lalki-barbie-cyrkonia-plaszcz-z-trenem-i6740511479.html-Ubranka dla lalki Barbie-CYRKONIA-płaszcz z trenem
http://allegro.pl/lalka-barbie-holiday-kolekcjonerska-barbi-swieta-i6740494038.html-

Thanks man!! ;)